# How to create a new thread that will run based off of the next ucontext_t in my ready queue

Tags: c, multithreading

So I am simulating multi threading through context switches. Now I actually need to create a new thread that will continue to run based off of the next context in my ready queue.

So I think I have a general idea of how this would work. I have a global ready queue that contains my ucontext_t structs. I want to essentially "pause" the running of the current thread and instead run the next ucontext_t on a new thread until I tell my application to stop waiting. My confusion is coming from how I would create this new thread and get it to run the next context. pthread_create needs a function pointer but I don't even know what function it will be running (isn't that determined by the context?).

Any insight on this problem would be greatly appreciated.

I've done some more reading and it seems that I am going to want to use clone(...) however the details are still eluding me.

Comment: it seems what is needed is a way to initially get the process/thread on the ready queue.  after that, you can use your current code to force context switches, etc

Comment: @user3629249 My main confusion is coming from what arguments I would even go about putting into clone. If I don't know the function how can I point to it?